# Maximum number of columns in PRIMARY KEY

Tags: mysql, mariadb

What is the maximum number of columns that can be used in a multi-column `PRIMARY KEY` in MariaDB?

I know about MySQL, but I can't find the limitation in MariaDB's documentation.

Comment: The same restrictions as in MySQL apply.

Comment: If you can't find something in MariaDB docs, look in MySQL docs.  They are both based on the same code.  Granted, there has been some divergence, but much is still the same.

Answer (score 3):

It's the same for MySQL and MariaDB: **an index can consist of 16 columns, at maximum**.
Since a `PRIMARY KEY` constraint automatically adds an index, it can't have more than 16 columns.

See [MySQL Reference Manual / ... / The Main Features of MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/features.html):

> Support for up to 64 indexes per table. **Each index may consist of 1 to 16 columns or parts of columns.** The maximum index width is 767 bytes (per column) for InnoDB tables, or 1000 for MyISAM. An index may use a prefix of a column for `CHAR`, `VARCHAR`, `BLOB`, or `TEXT` column types.

Comment: 5.7 increases the byte limit.  And it is per-column; there is a bigger limit on the entire index width.

Comment: @RickJames I just copied the official docs. Is the increase only for InnoDB tables and/or only through changing settings? In any case, the question was about that 16, not index width. That could be useful for the OP but they haven't tagged with a specific MAriaDB version.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ - True, 16 is not in question.  That 5.7 page may need fixing; please give me the link.  5.7.7 made some 5.6 options into default.  I summarize in my [_Limits_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits) blog.  I don't know if/when MariaDB will pick up the those settings.

Comment: @RickJames the link is there in my answer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/features.html (Under **Scalability and Limits**)

Comment: I filed http://bugs.mysql.com/84288 .